# Print Richedit's contents with zoom <> 100% with Delphi 11.3

Tags: delphi, trichedit

The TRichEdit control renders its contents on screen at various zoom values eg. 130%
I want to do the same on any canvas eg. of a picture or on printer's canvas.
Is there a way to do this programmatically ?